# Apache camel Kafka exception handling

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-camel

how to handle connection refused exception while pushing messages in the camel exchange to Kafka end point.Kafka may be down or it will be down during the process.. please help me how to handle this type of scenarios
I tried with onException block it is not working

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

`

```
.doTry()
    .to("kafka:....)
.endDoTry()
.doCatch(Exception.class)
  .to("direct:handleTechnicalCommunicationError")
.end()
```

`

Write a separete route direct:handleTechnicalCommunicationError for handling this error